# how to sort an array in c++ using command line turbo c++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I have an exercise for sort an array in c++. I'm coding with command line programming from turbo c++.

Comment: What did you try? Do you have the std library at your disposal in turbo c++? If you don't, then try implementing [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Comment: @duskwuff we are using that compiler coz our teacher said we must need to practice the coding so then we using that compiler

Comment: I know quicksort works because I used to use it back in the stone age.

Comment: Checkout sorting algorithms if you are not using STL...mergesort would be easy to start with

Comment: @Kay sorry sir i don't have that library in this compiler. Our teacher said we must use that turboc++ compiler to practice for us

Comment: So, what is your question? How to implement a sorting algorithm? I guess you will find pseudocode in Wikipedia. Do not copypaste a solution from here. Try to understand the idea behind the algorithm and write it down in C++. If you come across a problem then, then you can ask you a question **containing some code *you* wrote** back in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @kay sir i need to sort an array. only an array
it's may be integer or string anything

Comment: The Wikipedia [Sorting Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) page has many to chose from, most include an example implementation or pseudo-code. If you just want a simple to implement algorithm I suggest [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how i did it. Hope this is what you mean.

- Read the command line arguments
- Convert the string to integer using `atoi` function
- Sort using any sorting algorithm ([bubble sort](http://www.jterminal.com/bubble-sort-in-c/) used here)
- Print the result

To see how bubble sort works check out [this](http://www.jterminal.com/bubble-sort-in-c/).

```
    #include<iostream.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
     int i,j,temp, arr[10];

     for(i=1; i<argc; ++i)
     {
      arr[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
     }

     /* Sort the array using bubble sort alogrithm */
     for(i=0; i<argc-2; ++i)
     {
      for(j=0; j<argc-2; ++j)
      {
       if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
       {
        temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1] = temp;
       }
      }
     }

     /* Print the result */
     cout<<"Sorted array : ";
     for(i=0; i<argc-1; ++i)
     {
      cout<<" "<<arr[i];
     }
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: -1 for useless solution. OP can copy copy from all over the internet. SO is foremost for teaching!

Comment: Why useless? Don't you get output for this program? or is it not command line program?

Comment: You did not even try to explain the algorithm. How does your answer help OP? In the exam he won't be able to ask you to write his code. You need to explain how a swap works, why you need two loop, and so on to give a proper answer.

Comment: @Kay : Thanks for noticing.. i've added explanation and posted a link better explaining bubble sort

Comment: Sir there has an error it has atoi() function can u explain this

Comment: arguments passed through command line will be strings (not integers). So you'll need to convert it in to integer using atoi() function before sorting. atoi() converts string to integer.  Now you can simply run the program via command line : 
file_name.exe 23 12 45 2
will give you output:
2 12 23 45
check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) url for details of atoi() function

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code, it uses bubble sort algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort(int *,int);

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {2,3,4,12,5,0,2,5,1,20};
    sort(arr,10);
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}

void sort(int * ar,int length)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
        for(int j = i;j<length;j++)
        {
            if(ar[j] < ar[i])
            {
                int swap = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[j];
                ar[j] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

As I said it's based on the bubble algorithm. It sequentially checks the indexes from first one to last one and automatically puts the smallest number in first place, second smallest in second place and so on. You can see [here](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Arrays/Bubble.htm) or [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort) for more information.

Comment: -1 for useless solution. OP can copy copy from all over the internet. SO is foremost for teaching!

Comment: sir can i use that code from turbo c++????

Comment: @ChathuraBuddika: yes, you can.

Comment: @Kay: The question's fault, this is the answer of the question. Anyway I edited my answer

Comment: Sorry, but now I'll keep my down vote because your explanation of bubblesort in not quite good. There should be no need for the word "automatically" in description of an algorithm. And you don't have to answer bad questions. :-)

Comment: I understand, you have the right to vote down and you can use it however you see fit. Besides he's a new comer (as am I) and he doesn't know how this site works, so I answered and I was going to mention in my comment that the question was not a good one. As for the "automatically"; I used it to "summarize" the algorithm explanation because he most probably knows about this algorithms hence this is one of the most basic and fundamental subjects taught in different courses.

Comment: `cout << array` does not do what you think it does. Obviously, you didn't even bother to compile and run the code.

Comment: In that case the `if(ar[j] < ar[i])` statement would be `if(ar[j] > ar[i]`. So what you're saying is the mirror image of what I wrote here. As for your second comment edit, you're right, just edited my answer.

Comment: I removed my -1 because your answer is much better now. Still I don't think that such newcomer questions should be answered with full working code. Now OP is cheated from the need to struggle with the code. You need hindrances to improve yourself…

Comment: @Kay: I agree. Besides I'm glad I just learnt a bit more about what questions to answer and how to answer them correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @Vahid Nateghi bubble sort is the fastest (sort of ;) ) sorting algorithm to understand. If the op is enthusiastic enough to post on here but not search for a better solution to their problem then that's their fault not yours in my opinion (although you should preface your answer saying there are "better" options out there). +1 for an accurate solution that solves the problem.

Comment: i tried that code. it's doesn't work on the turbo c++

Comment: @ChathuraBuddika: Do you get an error? Try removing `using namespace std;`

Comment: no no
my code like this
        #include<iostream.h>
        #include<conio.h>

        int main()
        {
            getch();
            return 0;
        }
i got the error in getch();

Comment: @ChathuraBuddika: The `getch()` function is defined in `stdio.h` library ... Try adding `#include <stdio.h>` to the beginning of your code..

Comment: @vahidnateghi that i done that as you told. it was compiled successfully but it's doesn't run i don't know why is this. can u try this with turbo c++ compiler....?

Comment: @ChathuraBuddika: I couldn't find the compiler for now, (use better compilers as soos as you can) however from what I remember from last time I uses turbo c++ the code above without `using namespace std;` should work just fine in turbo C++.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation for chat :(